# PHP Schedule/ Trigger

Tags: php

I needed help for php schedule/trigger in order to change a specific column data.
My table consists of 3 coulmns id, blockTime and blockState.
blockTime is of data type date/time where by the time where the blocking time starts, and the blockState is set to Yes. After 5 minutes, the blockState should change to No and blockTime to Null for each id. 
That is if blockTime is 1 00, at 1 05 it should change the blockState.
Is it feasible ? If yes, can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for what is known as a `cron job`. This can run a script every five minutes. Then you just need to write a script that makes the change, and have the cron job call it.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, and depending on the version, you could possibly use the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

Comment: @PaulT  
`UPDATE regVoter SET blockState=0 WHERE blockTime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`

This is my sql in my event scheduler but it is not working, any reason why it is ? My scheduler is on.

Comment: Make sure that the event_scheduler is not off. Check with: `show variables like 'event%'` ... if that shows the value to be off, then you can enable it with: `set global event_scheduler = 1`.

Comment: ...more on my last comment. Know that setting that at the prompt will only last until the server restarts, so if you want it to be set when the mysqld starts, then add this line to your my.cnf file: `event_scheduler=ON`.  Know that OFF or 0 can be used for off, and ON or 1 can be used for on as [noted here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html)  If the event_scheduler is disabled at startup, then runtime toggling will have no effect. (also mentioned at the same link)

Comment: ...if it's still not working after that, append your table structure and the event definition to the bottom of your question and I could give it a try as well.

Comment: @PaulT. `*CREATE EVENT changeBlockedState
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
  DO    
   UPDATE regVoter SET blockState=0 WHERE blockTime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`

This my event scheduler code.

Comment: @PaulT.  My table has 3 columns id of type int, blockTime of type datetime and blockState of type tinyint(1)

Comment: A couple of more minutes to another two rows that I added, the first two were ok, blockstate set from 1 to 0 after 5 mins... 2nd test run ok. That was 4 rows (2 rows the first 5 min run, 2 other rows another 5 min run), that were both ok. Now I'll recreate the event to set the datetime to null as well.

Comment: @PaulT. It isn't working for me, i've set my event Scheduler Status on, can you please share the steps ? Thank you in advance

Comment: All I did was create the table with the 3 column that you mentioned, and I copy/pasted the create event (without the leading * ... is that a typo?) and then inserted 4 table rows with only two having the blockState=1. After the blockStates set to zero (have to refresh the table info), I added two more rows with blockState=1, and after 5 mins, these also set to 0.  That's it.  I'm checking to see if there another event status that you might be able to check.

Comment: Check `show status like 'Executed_events' `. That will give a count of how many events have fired. Run that a few times to verify that the count is increasing. If that is increasing, then the event is firing, as this is likely the only event that you have, correct?

Comment: If you need to change the event, you have to first drop the event `DROP EVENT changeBlockedState` and then recreate it. Setting the blockTime=null as mentioned in your question along with blockState=0 is working fine too. I used `CREATE EVENT changeBlockedState ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND DO UPDATE regVoter SET blockState=0, blockTime=NULL WHERE blockTime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`  If you need to see the list of events, you can use the command `SHOW EVENTS` to verify that your event name is listed.

Comment: Know that the blockTime column cannot have 'NOT NULL' specified in the table definition, or there will be errors when the `UPDATE` attempts to set NULL occur. The event will fail with no table changes on error, which will make it "seem as if the event is not working", but the event will keep executing, which can be verified by checking the `Executed_events` count.